# Javascript - multiple complex if statements

Tags: javascript

Im struggling with multiple complex statements in javaScript and wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction.

```
    function findFlights()
    {
    var yourDestination = readTheDestination();
    var yourAirline = readTheAirline();
    var yourFare = readTheFare();


    if (yourDestination == 'Choose your destination')
        {
        displayMessage('<B>Please choose a destination city from the Destination menu and then click Find flights again.</B>');
        }
    else
        {
        var destinationTime, destinationOperator, destinationFare;
        var message = '<B>You asked about flights to ' + yourDestination + '</B><BR>' + "";

        for (var i=0; i < flightTimes.length; i++)                      //flight destinations
        {
        if    // statement                                              // IF flight:
           ((flightDestinations[i] == yourDestination &&                // destination = selected destination &
            yourAirline == 'Any airline' &&                             // airline = any airline &
            yourFare == 'Any price'))                                    // fare <= chosen fare
            ||                                                          // OR
           (flightDestinations[i] == yourDestination &&                // destination = selected destination &
           yourAirline == flightOperators[i] &&                        // airline = chosen airline &
           yourFare <= flightFares[i]))                                // fare <= chosen fare

            {
            destinationTime = flightTimes[i];
            destinationOperator = flightOperators[i];
            destinationFare = flightFares[i];



            message += destinationTime + ' ' + destinationOperator + '. £' + destinationFare + '<BR>';
            displayMessage(message);

            }
        }
        else if (flightDestinations[i] == yourDestination && 
                flightOperators[i] != yourAirline && 
                flightFares[i] != yourFare)
            {
            displayMessage('There are no flights to ' + yourDestination + ' with ' + yourAirline + '. Please select Any Airline and try again.');
            }
        }
```

This is what I have so far and its making me gray.

Comment: uh... is there a question here?

Comment: You should describe what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Is the issue the `if` statement quantity? or whether there is a better way to do this task that you showed us?

Comment: First of all, correct all errors (JSLint), format the code (JSBeautifier) ....

Answer (score 7):

**Refactor complex code to function**

If you have complex if statements try and wrap them up in functions. So

```
(flightDestinations[i] == yourDestination &&
yourAirline == 'Any airline' &&
yourFare == 'Any price')
```

could become

```
function YourDestinationIsTheSameForAnyAirlineOrPrice(flightDestination, yourDestination, yourAirline, yourFare){
    return flightDestination == yourDestination &&
        yourAirline == 'Any airline' &&
        yourFare == 'Any price';
}

// And called from if
if (YourDestinationIsTheSameForAnyAirlineOrPrice(flightDestinations[i], yourDestination, yourAirline, yourFare)) {}
```

Rather than trying to decipher the if statement you have a function name telling you what it does.

**Use an object over multiple arrays**

Specific to your example I would also try and create a single flight object that contains the destination, time and airline. eg:

```
var flight = {
    destination = "London",
    operator = "BA",
    time = "18:00 UTC",
    fare = "£239829"
}
```

This should make the code more readable than using multiple arrays. Example:

```
destinationTime = flightTimes[i];
destinationOperator = flightOperators[i];
destinationFare = flightFares[i];

message += destinationTime + ' ' + destinationOperator + '. £' + destinationFare + '<BR>';

// Using an object
message += flight.time + ' ' + flight.operator + '. £' + flight.fare + '<br />';
```

**Return early**

Finally I would break out of the function as soon as possible. So use:

```
if (yourDestination == 'Choose your destination') {
    displayMessage('<B>Please choose a destination city from the Destination menu and then click Find flights again.</B>');
    return;
}
```

instead of an if...else. I personally find this more readable, so feel free to ignore this.

Comment: I wish I was learning this from another source, but I have to work within the confined of my tutors, I have picked up some tips now to change what Im  looking at so will go with them, will ask again if get stuck further. thanks

Comment: Mate, you forgot to put the `return` at the beginning of the function `YourDestinationIsTheSameForAnyAirlineOrPrice` otherwise that is a great solution.

Comment: Thanks @Puiu. Good spot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You've mismatched your parenthesis here:

```
((flightDestinations[i] == yourDestination &&                // destination = selected destination &
 yourAirline == 'Any airline' &&                             // airline = any airline &
 yourFare == 'Any price'))                                    // fare <= chosen fare
 ||                                                          // OR
(flightDestinations[i] == yourDestination &&                // destination = selected destination &
yourAirline == flightOperators[i] &&                        // airline = chosen airline &
yourFare <= flightFares[i]))                                // fare <= chosen fare
```

Change `yourFare == 'Any price'))` to `yourFare == 'Any price')`.

Comment: I know, I have changed them on my hard copy, was just easier for posting, I have also used tabs to indent so I can see where the statements are supposed to go.  Apparently we have been taught using very old writing style and not sure if thats whats causing problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the question is, but you should use more consistent indentation and the complex `if` statements will definitely become clearer.

My rules:

- use tabs to indent your lines of code according to scope (e.g. +1 tab while within curly braces, `if` statements, etc.)
- do not use tabs for anything else; use spaces for alignment, multiple spaces if necessary (so, use spaces to line up your conditions in the `if` statement if the statement spans multiple lines)

Comment: his indentation could have been messed up from copy & pasting, it looks like there is a form of indentation.  Not really an answer here.

Comment: Sorry, my question is can you have so many if/or's in the statement.

Comment: Im working on the second If statement.  I need it to have the selected destination, the selected airline and the fare to be less than or equal to the selected amount, its not happy with what I added here.

Comment: @amamam: you should update the question as well.  But, there is no limit to the number of conditionals you can have in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think that this is not a necessary tuning, you can write the code as follows:

```
if (yourDestination == 'Choose your destination') {
    displayMessage('<B>Please choose a destination city from the Destination menu and then click Find flights again.</B>');
    return;
}
```

This helps you remove the `else` and its brackets `{...}`.

You can change the for loop to reduce the code size:

```
if(flightDestinations[i] != yourDestination) continue;
```

So that, you don't need to write this condition repeatedly.

Comment: may souond stupid but, does the break mean the script will stop at that point, we not been told the break in tutorials

Comment: No, it doesn't stop. It just gets to the next cycle without executing the code afterwards. i is incremented and iteration continues.